# Kafka offset manual commit not updating offset value

Tags: python, apache-kafka, confluent-platform, confluent-kafka-python

My python confluent kafka code to read from the Kafka broker looks as below

```
self.consumer = Consumer(
            {
                "auto.offset.reset": "earliest",
                "enable.auto.commit": False,
            }
        )

while True:
        msg = self.consumer.poll(timeout=5)
        log.info(f"Before commit  {msg.topic()} {msg.partition()} 
        {msg.offset()}")
        #Before commit  stream-seg 2 6476

        self.consumer.commit(asynchronous=False)

        log.info(f"After commit  {msg.topic()} {msg.partition()} 
        {msg.offset()}")
        #After commit  stream-seg 2 6476
```

**As seen above the msg.offset() before and after commit is same**. Should I commit the offset value/partition also while doing the consumer.commit() or am I missing something

Answer (score 1):

You never change the `msg` variable, so there is no modification done to its attributes as a side-effect of committing.